# How do you reuse a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uipickerview

I have a UITableView with 13 cells.

I need to select options for each using a Picker Wheel but I don't want or think I need to create 13 View Controllers with nothing but a Picker Wheel on the VC.

I'm guessing I can use just one view controller to do this. Can I use else-if statements and reuse the same View Controller with the UIPickerView on it?

That way I would only have 1 View Controller to Segue to and one .swift file linked to it instead of 13 VC's and 13 .swift files.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the UIKit tools are built for reusability. What you need to be looking at is UIPickerViewDataSource and the UIPickerViewDelegate protocols. Conforming to these protocols will force you to implement the methods required to send the pickerView data.

There are a few methods associated with these protocols, all of them play a part in customizing some aspect of the table and will be useful in modifying what the user will see on the table. For example:

```
optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
```

is the method that lets you modify the 'titles' (contents of each row) of the UIPickerView scroller.

In your case, to display different data using a single pickerView, you will put the if statements inside this method to manipulate what this method sends back to the pickerView.

What you want to do is have some kind of mechanism to differentiate which of the 13 piece of information you want to use in the pickerView, which you would handle in the aforementioned method.